# MCP23016(I2C pin expander) not detected when pullups are present

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, i2c, esp32

I am using an ESP32 which has multiple devices connected to it via I2C(4 Attinies, MPU6050 and MCP23016(pin expander)). I2C scanner wasn't detecting it when pullup resistors(4.7k) were anywhere on the bus. When I removed all of the pullups, the scanner found the expander and all of the other devices. I haven't had this problem with any other I2C devices and it seems really strange to me. How could this happen, and is there any way to fix this behaviour? I am attaching my schematic.
[image]

Comment: Are you 100% certain there are no pull-ups on the I2C bus? Are the other devices bare IC's you've soldered on a board, or are they modules? If they are modules, chances are that they have build-in pull-up. If there are really no pull-up, the I2C bus can't work.

Comment: Measure the resistance across the line (v+ to sda and v+ scl). If you removed all the pull ups, it should be open. Measure the voltage between v+ and sda or scl. It should be open or not 0. Measure the voltage between sda or scl and ground. It should not be v+.

Comment: ATTiny's have internal pull-ups on Port B, but they're pretty weak. How large/small is the bus? If it's pretty small, and thus the capacitance is small, then the internal pull-ups should make it work, although it's not recommended to omit the externals. Can you post a full schematic?